# Has S#harp Architecture been updated to work in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, s#arp-architecture

Is anyone out there using S#harp Architecture with VS 2010/.Net 4.0? We are looking for a good ASP.Net MVC framework, and the guys here are already familiar with NHibernate and Spring.Net, so S#harp Arch seems like a good fit. However, they are rolling out VS2010 this week, so we need to know if/how well it will work in VS2010.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S#arp Architecture 1.5 has been released. It provides support for both VS 2008 and VS 2010. The latest version is 1.5.2. You will find the download at:

http://github.com/codai/Sharp-Architecture/downloads

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question. I found this post after more thorough searching of the Sharp Architecture group, which was posted on April 7th:

> Eric, 
>   I hate to be the bearer of bad news but, this version DOES NOT
>   support  VS 2010. Once v1.5 is
>   released, I will concentrate on VS
>   2010 support as  well as migrations.
>   Then we are off to EF 4 support. While
>   I realize VS 2010  is coming on the
>   12th (or so I've heard), Billy and I
>   both felt that  supporting two
>   templates was not a good idea given
>   the time maintaining one  takes. With
>   that said, v1.5 will be the last
>   version to support VS 2008. All 
>   future versions will support VS 2010
>   until another version comes out.  Now
>   if you want to get it working and get
>   a wiki page together, I for one  would
>   be most appreciative.
>   Cheers,
>   Alec Whittington